# Array in magento 2

Tags: php, magento2.2, image-upload

In below code,I want to **save only** the **name** in **DB**. But How do i get name only from below array. Please suggest me a solution to get a name

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => boy_1_6.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpti6eaW
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 33454
            [file] => boy_1_6.jpg
            [url] => http://localhost/magento220/pub/media//boy_1_6.jpg
            [previewType] => image
        )

)
```

Comment: is every time get only 0 id data?

Comment: No. I have passed id as null

Comment: can you write your code how you get that array?

Comment: I am saving a ui form in DB. All the fields  are saved in DB except image.But for image i got the above array.I did not know how to resolve it

Comment: Please refer this below link , then you can have better understand about my  problem.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201658/ui-form-image-not-saved-in-db-in-magento-2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

if the array store is variable $arr

than access name  just like below

```
$arr[0]['name']
```