# Ui form: image not saved in DB in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, image-upload, ui-form

I need to save below fields in DB. All other fields are saved  except Image.But images are saved in **pub/media** folder.Please suggest me a solution

Here, i have mentioned my controller for **save.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace Namespace\HomeSlider\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

    class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {

        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
        )
        {
            $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $postModel = $this->_objectManager->create('Namespace\HomeSlider\Model\Post');

            if ($id) {
                $postModel = $postModel->load($id);
            }  
            $post = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
      //     echo<pre>;
    //       print_r($post); 
  //         echo</pre>;
     //        exit;
            if(empty($post['id'])) {
                 $post['id'] = null;
             }

            $postModel->setData($post);
            $postModel->save();
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('homeslider/post/index');
        }

    }
```

The parameters are below what i get. But the image is stored as array of array format . How do I overcome this.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just add these two line before  **$postModel->setData($post)**

```
$imageName = $post['image'][0]['file'];
$post['image'] = $imageName;
```

Comment: Thank you . I have solved the issue but it is properly working for new action But it is failed to work for edit action in UI form

Answer (score 0):

In your save action instead of `$postModel->setData($post);` set data individually. Like below

```
$postModel->setColumnName($post['param_name_of_column']);
```

Do this for all the Column and for image you can do like below

```
$postModel->setImage($post['image'][0]['name']);
```

and Then save the model using `$postModel->save();`

Comment: I have solved the issue in other way. But it is failed to load exiting image what i was stored in DB while  pressing edit

Comment: check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/201018/20064

Comment: Am i need to set each colum like this way  which you mentioned above ?

Comment: Is this a optimized way?

Comment: No, it is same as Qaisar's Answer

Comment: I have done as you said , But now, it did'nt save even a single field

Comment: Yes I am using Qaisar's answer. But it is failed to fetch image from DB while editing.

Comment: Thank you .It works fine . But failed to bring preview and size of the image while editing

Comment: you can follow this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184731/magento-2-implement-ui-fileuploader/186781#186781

Answer (score -1):

First,add use **Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList** to this class.

Then add below for add code for upload image

```
try{

 $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
    'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
    ['fileId' => 'image']
    );
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
    $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
    $uploader->addValidateCallback('catalog_product_image', $imageAdapter, 'validateUploadFile');
    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
    $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
    ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('emizen_banner'));
    if($result['error'] == 0){
    $path = 'emizen_banner' .$result['file'];
    }
    //sucessFully upload
} catch (\Exception $e) {
}
```